# How were scriptures, stotras & other texts preserved from the ancient ages to the modern days?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, vedanta, stotra, manuscripts

We have two main itihasas, ramayan and mahabharat and hundreds of stotras which actually say in viniyoga that they were given by many ancient rishis or figures like bhishma or various gods and goddesses. How did all these successfully journey forward without getting lost in time?

Comment: Stotras were originally found in Puranas and Tantras. Some Stotras are independent works of Rishis and some are found in Itihasas too. So they are preserved in the same way the scriptures are preserved. If the scriptures get lost then the Stotras also get lost and vice versa.

Comment: But how did mahabharat text journey forward in time without getting altered?

Comment: Then your question should be "how is Mahabharata preserved over time?" Not sure if it is asked already or not if not you can ask it.

Comment: The scriptures are copied again and again from one paper or palm leafs to new one, and this process is done by lot of different people (who are expert copyists) differently in diffrent areas where manuscripts are or were kept safe. That's also the reason why we get many manuscripts of the same text (might be complete  or incomplete) of course many verses show variations. When it's time to publish these, all avaliable versions of a text are studied and the appropriate is published.